# oledbtransaction & oledbconnection lifetime

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, transactions

i'm doing an application in asp.net using a class stack of my authorship to abstract some complexity of the database and the interaction in it is done using 1 connection among all the classes; constantly opening /closing connection and executing oledbcommands on readers, datasets, etc.

and i need to implement a transaction to encapsulte a big chunck of queries

my concrete question is:

*my transaction will be lost when my first open/close finish or will persistt among all the page until dispose event is reached?*

Note= i'm not setting null/nothing on connection only closing and oppening when i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transaction will be rolled back when you close the connection.